# Storyboard with Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uistoryboard

Folks,
I Need help about Storyboard. 
I have a Storyboard with a Table and a View, I want to click in a cell and do a transaction to a view.
I set DetalheMeuPostoAmigo to View and call it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath as code bellow.

When I run aplication I don't receive any error, but the transaction don't function too.
I tested with alert and did OK. I reviewed the code many many times...

```
 Top10.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];   
   DetalheMeuPostoAmigo *detalhesMeuPostoAmigoVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetalheMeuPostoAmigo"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:detalhesMeuPostoAmigoVC animated:YES];
}
```

[Link to Storyboard Image](https://docs.google.com/open?id=1aYJU7mG0yvpVv0P_sQSX4HsATlfPtjcerXnQUM7wJFmHThMP7xIIdR3EwC6L)

Comment: try this:   UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard; instead of thisUIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

Comment: Tks Rahul, I tryed but didn't worked, Do you have another ideia ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert on this, but try using the existing VC:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];    
   YOURCURRENTVC *detalhesMeuPostoAmigoVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetalheMeuPostoAmigo"]; 
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:detalhesMeuPostoAmigoVC animated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: Tks Romo, I tryed but didn't worked, Do you have another ideia ?

Comment: This is how I do it in my project:

Comment: UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BOARDvc"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

Comment: Goood, Thanks very much Romo.

Comment: Follow the code its ok:

  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetalheMeuPostoAmigo"];
    
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    
    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer. But i had similar problems in the past. Check if self.navigationController == null if it's null here is your problem.

Boa sorte

Comment: Tks Sérgio, I tryed but didn't worked, Do you have another ideia ?

Comment: If you have a ViewController inside another ViewController you may have to call the ViewController that is your 'mainViewController'.
Try to make the push from another viewcontroller.

I just saw your test. Try To call from other viewcontroller. sometimes i have mutiple viewcontroller not all have a navigationcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just have Segue created on the table cell? Select table cell, press control key and drag arrow to your view controller and select push. Give identifier to the Segue and you are done!

The problem with your code is you don't have UITableview embaded in UINavigationController. Embed it by selecting "Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller". Then your code should work.

FYI this [articles](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) on storyboards are awesome!

Comment: Tks applefreak, I tryed but didn't worked, Do you have another ideia ?

Comment: What did you try? there's no complication in your problem. It should work straight way. Read those articles and you will master storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial ViewController is not in a NavigationController.

On your storyboard select the TableViewController and from the menu select

**Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers, I tested all options but didn't have success, below the  Sérgio's test

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

        DetalheMeuPostoAmigo *detalhesMeuPostoAmigoVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetalheMeuPostoAmigo"];


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detalhesMeuPostoAmigoVC animated:YES];

    if (detalhesMeuPostoAmigoVC == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Is null?"); // Here is not Null

    }
    if (self.navigationController == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Is null?"); // Here is Null

    }
```